# Order By ? in classic asp risk

Tags: asp-classic

In an application that I'm working on containing classic asp. I have this error thrown:

> The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name.

Now this is because using `Order By ?`, but if I use `Order By Case when ? = ? then ? end` then the error does not occur.

Parameters are added like this for specific number of parameters introduced.

```
.Parameters(k) = Session("ORDER1")          
dc.Item("ORDER1") = false
k = k + 1
.Parameters(k) = Session("ORDER1") 
k = k + 1
.Parameters(k) = Session("ORDER1") 
k = k + 1
```

To me this seems like a weird work around. Is there any issue in doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly what it says: you cannot use a variable in an order by clause.
You will get the same error with this simple TSQL:

```
declare @x int
set @x=1
select * from SomeTable order by @x
```

But case...when does not use a variable, but return a value, that's why it works.